# Codeigniter showing the session of another user

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, web-hosting

This is my first question in stackoverflow. So please excuse me if i do any mistake. For few days I am facing a very wired problem for the first time using Codeigniter 2.2.0, I searched a lot but could not find any solution. First let me explain my problem.

When User "A" logged in from his pc or mobile he has his own session, but when another user "B" logged in from another pc he sees all the data of user "A". Again when another user logged in he see a Random users data like "A" or "B". The codes are working fine on my local server xampp running Php 5.6 but when i upload it to my hostgrator shared hosting server then it starts misfunctioning. I tried changing different php version from 5.4 to 5.6 but got the same result.

I contact with their support they told me that everything is perfect on their side.

Here is my code for login controller

```
    function verifyUsers() {

    $mobile = $this->input->post("mobile");
    $userPass = $this->input->post("pass");
    if ($this->setting->checkUser($mobile, $userPass)) {
        $userInfo = $this->setting->getUserID($mobile);
        $data = array(
            'mobile' => $mobile,
            'uid' => $userInfo[0]->uid,
            'name' => $userInfo[0]->first_name,
            'mobile' => $userInfo[0]->mobile,
            'image' => $userInfo[0]->image,
            'reg_date' => $userInfo[0]->reg_date,
            'user_logged' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('info', $data);
        redirect('portal');
    } else {
        $code = "log_failed";
        $data['msg'] = "Incorrect Id Or Password";
        $this->load->view('web/user_login_view', $data);
    }
}
```

and here is my portal controller. I have just print the session data to check.

```
function index() {

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Is there any problem on my code or on the hosting?

Comment: please check the session in the starting of your controller

Comment: I've seen 2-3 people post the same question on Stack. I'd link them if I could find them. Although I cannot help you with CI2x I would recommend upgrading if you can as the session system in 2x notoriously had major issues.

Comment: try with this code :  `$this->session->set_userdata($data);`

Comment: it can't be. session seaves in browser-based not system or user based

Comment: @pradeep I tried this. but did not work

Comment: make sure u have unique mobile number for each user

Comment: ya i have unique users.. Its working perfectly on my localhost but not on server